# How To: Delete Rows and Columns Selectively in a CSV file from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, row, multiple-columns

My question is probably fairly simple, but I haven't been able to get it right yet.

I am working on a program that compares csv files for a certain physics application, that however is not the problem. The files that I need to compare have two columns with several thousands row values for those 2 columns, however, there are also extraneous rows and columns above that point which are causing the problem.

First, here is the CSV file and you can obviously see the extra rows and column values I need to replace. 
[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f50um.jpg)

Pratically speaking, I only need to remove the first 24 rows.

Once I have done that, I would like to move all the values up so that row 25 becomes row 1, while moving all subsequent rows up as well.

The whole reason I am going to that trouble is so that I can use the following code to strip the CSV data and do complex calculations on it:

```
import csv
with open('Unknown69-Spectra-Bloom_.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Energy'], row['Counts'])
```

I would really appreciate your help. The simpler the solution, the better. My goal is to take the two columns, energy and counts, and then run their values in my full program.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I converted your image of code to actual code and edited it into your answer.  Don't post images of code.  It's the fastest way to turn people off from answering your questions here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use pandas, which makes this sort of thing really easy:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=24, header=None, names=[
    'Energy', 'Counts'])
print(df2['Energy'])
print(df2['Counts'])
```

You can access these arrays from the dataframe in various ways, easiest being
Then you have a pandas dataframe, which is a collection of numpy arrays.

You could also use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
df = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', skip_header=24, delimiter=',')
```

Which will also give you a collection of numpy arrays.  If you are skipping the rows at read-in time, then you do not need to reset the index.
It is possible to do this using csv, but pandas and numpy are very useful, so if you are willing to give them a go, they can be great at data processing.

Docs:

pandas:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

numpy:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Okay thanks! I'm fairly new to python, so I had never heard of pandas or numpy before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So you only want the first two columns and rows after 24?

```
import csv

in_file = open("whatever.csv", "r")
out_file = open("whatever_transformed.csv", "w", newline="")

in_csv = csv.reader(in_file)
out_csv = csv.writer(out_file)

for row_number, row in enumerate(in_csv):
    if row_number >= 24:
        out_csv.writerow(row[:2])

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I actually want all rows attached to the two columns after row 24, but I can do that part myself. Let me try this out and see how it works!

Comment: I'm probably being stupid but I'm not sure what a "row attached to a column" means. Can you describe the shape of the data a bit more precisely?

Comment: So your idea is giving me this error code which I'm unsure of how to bypass. 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Unknown69-Spectra-Bloom_.csv'

Comment: You probably have the file open in Excel. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be to skip over unwanted lines before creating your `DictReader`:

```
with open('Unknown69-Spectra-Bloom_.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    nskiplines = 24
    for _ in range(nskiplines):
        next(csvfile)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```